# Using google spreadsheet as an datasource for core data objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, google-sheets

Before reinventing the wheel i'm looking for code that pulls data from google spreadsheets and storing them in core data objects and vice versa.

Has anyone seen an objective-c project on the web that does exactly that? I want my users editing their data on spreadsheets and syncing it back to their mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

You might be intrested in the [Google Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/spreadsheets/). Calls to this API will return an XML representation of the actual Spreadsheet - all you have to do is parse this. I'm pretty sure there already are good XML-parsers for Objective-C out there.

Comment: Thanks, there even is a obj-c api from google and I started to use this, but i hope that anyone already solved that point especially syncing, etc.